# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/spi/TransactionalDataRegion in hibernate 5.3.1

Tags: hibernate, maven, migration

I'm using hibernate, I have update from hibernate 5.2.x to hibernate 5.3.1 and now I have this error on runtime.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/spi/TransactionalDataRegion in hibernate 5.3.1

In which dependency is org/hibernate/cache/spi/TransactionalDataRegion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help,
but this dependency was already in my app pom.xml.

Comment: Looks like file is currupted. Delete the file from .m2  repository  folder and add it again manually or  by install command by maven.

Comment: Simply update all my dependencies and it's work very well